# sqlite query from list of value

Tags: mysql, sqlite

This code is working within MS SQL Server

```
   SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('1234'), ('5678'), ('8888')) 
    AS Table_Staff_No(Staff_No)
    WHERE Staff_No 
    NOT IN (
        SELECT Staff_No 
        FROM Table_Staff_No 
        WHERE  (Staff_No IN ('1234', '5678'. '8888'))
```

How should I go about it in SQLite?

My table will be have value 1234, so I am passing my list (1234,5678,8888) to check which value is not exist in my table.

The result should be show 5678, 8888.

Answer (score 3):

Translating this query to SQLite requires a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), which is available since SQLite 3.8.3:

```
WITH Table_Staff_No(Staff_No) AS (
  VALUES ('1234'), ('5678'), ('8888')
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Table_Staff_No
WHERE Staff_No NOT IN (
    SELECT Staff_No 
    FROM Table_Staff_No 
    WHERE Staff_No IN ('1234', '5678', '8888'));
```

Comment: after execute, the result shows SQLiteStudio was unable to extract metadata from the query. Results won't be editable..

Comment: The output of a query never is editable. If you do not want get a (read-only) list of values out of the query, edit the question to show what your actual problem is.

Comment: Hi CL, I had the error base {System.Exception} = {"SQLite error\r\nnear \"WITH\": syntax error"}. Try to check my SQL version with SQLStudio 3.0.7 showing SQLite Version is 3.8.10 but check with SQL Browser version 2.0b1 showing SQLite Version is 3.6.18